# How to render \left( \right) in python

Tags: python, ipython

I'm trying to print a Latex expression in the Ipython terminal, so I'm using this code:

```
from IPython.display import display, Math, Latex

display(Math("$$E[\hat{r_x}(k)] = \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n = |k|}^{N-1} \
                  E[x(n)x^*(n-|k|)]=$$"))
display(Math("$$= \dfrac{1}{N} \sum_{n = |k|}^{N-1} r_x(|k|) = \
              \dfrac{r_x(k)}{N} (N-|k|) = r_x(k) \
              ( 1-\dfrac{|k|}{N} )$$"))
```

But the parenthesis around the fraction doesn't look good, so I tried to add `\left( \right)` to the expression, but it just shows me this:

[image]

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these instead of `\left( \right)`

```
display(Math("$$ \\big( \Big( \\bigg( \Bigg($$" ))
display(Math("$$ \\big[ \Big[ \\bigg[ \Bigg[$$" ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, reading your answer I came up with the idea of writing `\\left( \\right)` and it worked, but I'd appreciate if you could explain me why I have to use a double \\

Comment: In Latex we use only \b (for \big) but \b seems to have have some issues with the underlining html rendering of Jupiter notebooks. So to escape it we use the escape character "\" and make it \\big, this way it reached the Math mode properly.